# SharedPreferences not saving

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

Any changes in the SharedPreferences of my application are not reflected until I restart the 
application.
Specifically, I am using a ListPreference, depending on the item selected, the answer is changed (its a type of calculator). The changes are not made until I close and start the application again.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just one...post the code you are using to save

Comment: Do you commit the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure when you use the Editor class you call Editor.commit() after you make your changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't posted any code, it's a shoot in the dark... but if you want preferences to update things in your application, you have to listen to changes on preferences. Otherwise, only the preferences UI is updated.

See the [guide on listening for changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening) for more details.